Как создать one-to-many связь в sqlalchemy и alembic? python
при запуске команды alembic revision --message="Initial" --autogenerate и alembic upgrade head создаются все поля в базе postgreSQL, кроме поля stg, которое и является one-to-many. Что не так?
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Identity(always=True), primary_key=True)
    user: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(unique=True)
    stg: Mapped[List[Strategy]] = relationship()

class Strategy(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'strategy'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Identity(always=True), primary_key=True)
    symbol: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=False)
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("users.id"))

